# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoPermissions.Permissions.getAsync')]

Tags: react-native, expo

I can't get the token to the push notifications and permission doesn't work:

> Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoPermissions.Permissions.getAsync')

This is the code:

```
registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async ()=> {
  const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
  let finalStatus = status;
  if (status !== 'granted') {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    finalStatus = status;
  }
  if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
    return;
  }
  let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
  console.log(token);
}
```

Comment: Seems there is problem in `Permissions.getAsync` method.

Comment: can you post your exception

Comment: Have you imported permissions: `import { Permissions } from 'expo';`

Comment: What is your version of Expo?

Answer (score 9):

Permissions are moved from 'expo' package to 'expo-permissions'

You'll have to install expo-permissions package first then import it using the following syntax

```
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
```

Comment: Infact alots of packages are moved outside expo in newer versions. Its done to decrease the App sizes by not including the things that are not needed from expo.

Comment: I kept on installing `expo-permissions` from yarn, but it should be from `expo`. Like `expo install expo-permissions`

Answer (score 1):

I was using the right package, but I blindly wrote my import wrong. The way Rusty had it is still correct, but for others who were doing the right thing but maybe fell into this simple trap, be sure to check this too.

**DON'T import like this**:

```
import Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
```

**DO import like this**:

```
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
```

...If not you will see the same error message even using the CORRECT package!